# whether the ssh command successful or not?

Tags: expect, exit-status

I spawned ssh in expect script. in the script i have to check the exit status of ssh command on local machine to make some condition in that script using `if`/`else`.

```
spawn ssh user@192.168.1.1
       set success [exec echo \$?\r]
               if { $success == 0 } {
                       expect {
                               "(yes/no)? "
                               {send "yes\r"}
                               "password:"
                               {send "mypasswd\r"}
                               }
```

I think the problem is on 2nd and 3rd line, but don't know how to work with it.

Comment: I bypassed the ssh issue by "spawn ssh-keygen -R 192.168.1.1" but the if/else issue is still unsolved.